# How to append a df to another df, without NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to append `df1` to `data`. I used the code `combined = data.join(df1)`. But it returns a NaN values in the column i'm trying to add. The data column was extracted from yahoo finance which has a date column that i am unable to get rid of.
It returns this, which isnt what i want.
Could anyone assist me in appending the two df's together and getting the Date column into a reasonable column that I can edit on

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
data = data.fillna(df1)
```

Comment: It still doesnt work for me, still giving me NaN for that column

Comment: check `data.columns.intersection(df1.columns)` and `data.index.intersection(df1.index)` , dataframe.fillna search using rows and columns, make sure data.index type is equal df1.index type